# javascript select & highlight text in 2 blocks at the same time in textarea and div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

javascript select & highlight text in one of the blocks and highlight the text same time in textarea and div

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

when you select the text in textarea

my goal is when you select text in textarea or div block

show the highlighted text in both books at the same time

here is what need to look

[image]

here is my code

```js
function showPreview()
{
  var value = $('textarea').val().trim();
  value = value.replace("<", "&lt;");
  value = value.replace(">", "&gt;");
  $('#preview').html(value);
}
```

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

#preview { width:410px; 
border: solid 1px #999; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea   rows="10" cols="50" onInput="showPreview();">
  product noun
Save Word
To save this word, you'll need to log in.

Log In 
prod·​uct | \ ˈprä-(ˌ)dəkt  \
Definition of product
1: the number or expression resulting from the multiplication together of two or more numbers or expressions
2a(1): something produced
especially : COMMODITY sense 1
(2): something (such as a service) that is marketed or sold as a commodity
b: something resulting from or necessarily following from a set of conditions
a product of his environment
3: the amount, quantity, or total produced
4: CONJUNCTION sense 5
</textarea>
<br/>
<hr/>
<div id="preview">
</div>
```

right now highlights only when you select,  neet to highlight in both

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
let target = document.querySelector('#preview');
let plainLine = '\n';
let htmlLine = '<br/>';
let pressed = false;

function textToHtml(text) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp(plainLine, 'g'), htmlLine).replace(/\s\s/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;').replace(/^\s/g, '&nbsp;');
}

function htmlToText(html) {
    html = html.replace(new RegExp(htmlLine, 'g'), plainLine);
    return $('<div>').html(html).text();
}

function highlight(text, from, to) {
    let mark = text.slice(from, to);
    if (mark) mark = `<mark>${mark}</mark>`;
    return text.slice(0, from) + mark + text.slice(to);
}

function showPreview() {
    let from = textarea.selectionStart;
    let to = textarea.selectionEnd;
    let content = highlight(textarea.value, from, to);
    target.innerHTML = textToHtml(content);
}

$(textarea).on({
    mousedown: () => pressed = true,
    mouseup: () => pressed = false,
    mousemove: () => pressed && showPreview(),
    click: () => showPreview(),
    blur: () => showPreview()
});

showPreview();
```

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

#preview {
    width: 410px;
    border: solid 1px #999;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea   rows="10" cols="50" onInput="showPreview();">
  product noun
Save Word
To save this word, you'll need to log in.

Log In 
prod·​uct | \ ˈprä-(ˌ)dəkt  \
Definition of product
1: the number or expression resulting from the multiplication together of two or more numbers or expressions
2a(1): something produced
especially : COMMODITY sense 1
(2): something (such as a service) that is marketed or sold as a commodity
b: something resulting from or necessarily following from a set of conditions
a product of his environment
3: the amount, quantity, or total produced
4: CONJUNCTION sense 5
</textarea>
<br/>
<hr/>
<div id="preview">
</div>
```

Comment: amazing, can we reverse also? but is possible to select text inside div and highlight it in <textarea> ?

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: I updated the codes. Check again.

Comment: maybe you didn't save the changes, but look here  is not reversing https://codepen.io/maxoranew/pen/VwzvVwd if you select text inside the <div id="preview">
</div> is not  highlight it in the <textarea>

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that. This is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/pfswdu6k/

Comment: You should focus to the input after selection: textarea.focus()

Comment: i just checked your new link but still is not reversing the selection look here https://imgur.com/DiH6gTt   .  thank you i will work on selection: textarea.focus() this is not a problem.  now when i select text inside the <div> </div> is not highlighting the text inside the <textarea>

Comment: As I said, you should focus. It actually does but the selection doesn't appearance because of the input is not focused.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example:

```js
const preview = document.querySelector("#preview");

function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}

document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const selectedText = getSelectionText();
  if (selectedText !== "") {
    preview.innerHTML = preview.innerHTML.replaceAll(
      selectedText,
      `<mark>${selectedText}</mark>`
    );
  }
});

function showPreview() {
  let value = document.querySelector("textarea").value.trim();
  value = value.replace("<", "&lt;");
  value = value.replace(">", "&gt;");
  preview.innerHTML = value;
}
```

```css
::-moz-selection {
  /* Code for Firefox */
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

#preview {
  width: 410px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" onInput="showPreview();">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea>
<br />
<hr />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: very good, what if you want to select more than 1 time your demo right now, is not removing the selection or adding a new selection if you select different words. is possible to fix that?

Comment: Oh... I made a mistake. I edited your answer instead of mine. :/ How to cancel it?

Comment: i don't see any change in my code